# Time complexity of system of linear equations when distribution of variables are known

Tags: time-complexity

I have system of linear equations over binary field $GF(2)$. Suppose
there are $n$ equations with $n$ variables and equations are linearly independent.
Then we can solve using Gaussian elimination with $n^3$ complexity. We can improve this complexity using some advanced algorithms. Now suppose
we know few variables say $x_1, \ldots,x_m$ are zero with probability 0.9. Can we use
this information to improve time complexity?

Comment: If $m\ll n$, then you can't hope for much improvement: you can't do better than $T(n-m)$ time, where $T(n)$ is the time to solve a system with $n$ equations and $n$ variables (otherwise you could take any system of equations and add a few that are 0 with probability 0.9).

Comment: @D.W: Will you kindly email me     sarkar.malay.bir@gmail.com. I would like to discuss research problems.